# How can I use rollbar in an NPM package + source maps?

Tags: javascript, npm, source-maps, rollbar

I'm trying to use rollbar in an npm package that will be used as a dependency in other projects.

However, the errors I get are not showing up nicely on rollbar. Strangely enough, when I run a sample app that uses the dependency, I do see a proper error on the web console. 
I think the problem may be with source maps, but I haven't been able to properly configure it. Has anyone used rollbar to track errors on an npm package?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi there, Jesse on the Rollbar team here.  The best way to get an answer to your question is to contact our tech support team via support@rollbar.com or the in-app chat.  All customers are eligible for tech support, even if you're on a free plan.

Comment: Thanks @JesseGibbs, will do!

Comment: @JesseGibbs Seems support@rollbar.com doesn't exist, do you have any other email I can write to?

Comment: support@rollbar.com is the email for our support helpdesk.  It should work.  You can also contact us via the in-app chat in the lower right corner.